# Dev on extension package against unmanaged version of base package

Tags: managed-package, namespace, release, extension, developer-productivity

We are currently developing both an extension and base package. Currently, due to namespaces, we are forced to develop the extension package against a managed base package. When we have to change the base package during extension development (e.g. make a function global so it can be accessed in the ext.) we need to make a new managed package and push it into our ext dev orgs.

This is horrible as it means we can't just produce one base package per release and it is far too easy to accidentally include items in the base package during prod releases. This is becase we have a large dev team working on this and we need to give our devs access to the packaging org as packaging the base is needed daily for development.

So, what we would like is to be able to develop the extension package against unmanaged base code. This would make dev much faster and massively reduce bugs. To achieve this, we need a way around the namespace issue. The other alternatives I can think of are to have a dev packaging org that produces packages with the same namespace as the prod packaging org or to combine the base and ext packages, but this is undesirable for a number of reasons I won't go into.

Thoughts and ideas?